# "if" statement syntax differences between C and C++

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, cross-language

```cpp
if (1) int a = 2;
```

This line of code is valid C++ code (it compiles at the very least) yet invalid C code (doesn't compile). I know there are differences between the languages but this one was unexpected.

I always thought the grammar was

```
if (expr) statement
```

but this would make it valid in both.

My questions are:

1. Why doesn't this compile in C?
2. Why does this difference exist?

Comment: Which compiler? What is the error?

Comment: Could you send what error are you getting while compiling, and as lakeweb said, what compiler are you using

Comment: *why does this difference exist?* I would answer: because C and C++ are different programming languages.

Comment: See bolov's answer below for a more meaningful reason as to why the difference exists.

Comment: As answers below have pointed out, this happens whenever a _statement_ is expected, hence not limited to `if`. This includes "the line after" `for`, `while`, `switch` and labels, to name a few.

Comment: Another place that shows the difference is that you can't add a label to a declaration in C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, just tried and I seem to be able to add a label or case before a declaration just fine in C99 and C11.

Comment: @KlaasvanAarsen: Testing, especially with GCC, is not informative. [§6.8.1 Labelled statements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.1) specifies that only statements can be labelled and [§6.8.2 Compound statement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2) specifies that block statements consist of sequences of declarations and statements.  The grammar for Standard C does not allow labels on declarations.  C++ does allow them; some C compilers may allow it, but it is an extension over (current) Standard C.  C2x may change that.

Comment: `if (1) int a = 2;` does this just declare and initialize a variable which immediately goes out of scope?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is a subtle and important difference between C and C++.  In C++ *any* statement may be a *declaration-statement*.  In C, there is no such thing as a *declaration-statement*; instead, a *declaration* can appear instead of a *statement* within any *compound-statement*.

From the C grammar (C17 spec):

> *compound-statement*: "{" *block-item-list*<sub>opt</sub> "}"
> *block-item-list*: *block-item* | *block-item-list* *block-item*
> *block-item*: *declaration* | *statement*

From the C++ grammar (C++14 spec):

> *compound-statement*:
> "{" *statement-seq*<sub>opt</sub> "}"
> *statement-seq*:
> *statement* |
> *statement-seq* *statement*
> *statement*: ... | *declaration-statement* | ...

It is not clear *why* this difference exists, it is just the way the languages evolved.  The C++ syntax dates all the way back to (at least) C++85.  The C syntax was introduced sometime between C89 and C99 (in C89, declarations had to be at the beginning of a block)

---

In the original 85 and 89 versions of C++, the scope of a variable defined in a *declaration-statement* was "until the end of the enclosing *block*").  So a declaration in an `if` like this would not immediately go out of scope (as it does in more recent versions) and instead would be in scope for statements following the if in the same block scope.  This could lead to problems with accessing uninitialized data when the condition is false.  Worse, if the var had a non-trivial destructor, that would be called when the scope ended, even if it had never been initialized!  I suspect trying to avoid these kinds of problems is what led to C adopting a different syntax.

Comment: Imho, C moving to the C++ definition would simplify the language by removing gotchas, in addition to removing accidental differences. Just a shame they didn't do it in C99 when following common practice and allowing statements and definitions to mix.

Answer (score 75):

[Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72843033/2805305) (and others) shows how the grammar is different.

I want to point out that `if (1) int a = 2;` doesn't make sense in C but it does in C++. Since we don't have a block but just 1 statement/declaration there is no possible further use of the variable declared (it goes out of scope immediately). In C this would make no sense to allow, but in C++ constructors and destructors can have side effects, so defining and initializing a variable that goes out of scope immediately can be useful and must be allowed.

Comment: However, the address could be used. `int a=foo(&a);`.

Comment: @tstanisl But what's a possible use case for that? All I can think of is if `foo()` requires a pointer to an output location and you don't need that result.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, but `foo()` may have some side effects and it may require some external storage to do the job. Though using compound literal `foo(&(int){0})` may be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: It's equally useful/useless in either language, being lawful in only one is just an accidental difference.

Comment: @Deduplicator Good point. Just because you *can* use the variable just for its constructor/destructor side effect doesn't mean you *should*. Hiding semantics there makes for very obscure coding.

Comment: @tstanisl However, the `foo(&(int){0})` syntax fully initializes the object before passing its address, while the `int a = foo(&a);` syntax does not touch the memory of `a` until after `foo()` has returned. Another slight and subtle difference that could conceivably change the semantics of the program.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica: If you ever actually wanted to do this in C, it's trivial to wrap `{}` around the declaration that includes a function call.  Then it becomes legal even in C89.  It is a weird quirk of the grammar that that's needed, though, but it doesn't really need fixing since there's always a workaround that's equivalent, even for optimization purposes, in (all, I hope) real-world compilers.

Comment: @PeterCordes I never intended to abuse C in such a way. I merely commented on the fact that the two variants do exhibit different behavior, i.e. that they are not equivalent. That does not mean that I would ever rely on this behavior difference. Code should be as simple as possible, after all.

Answer (score 28):

It's because C and C++ define *statement* differently.

In C, declarations are not classified as statements. A C compound statement consists of an opening `{`, an option list of *block-item*s, and a closing `}`, where a *block-item* either a *declaration* or a *statement*. (This was changed in C99, when C added the ability to mix declarations and statements within a block.)

In C++, a declaration is classified as a statement (but only if it's inside a compound statement). This allows a simpler definition of a *compound-statement*: it's a `{`, followed by an optional list of *statement*s, followed by a `}`.

The difference doesn't have much practical effect; it's always possible to work around it. One effect is that it's legal in C++ for a declaration immediately follow a case label, but in C it's not legal.

Answer (score 15):

In C, a *declaration* and a *statement* are distinct entities.

In C++, a a subset of declarations called a *block-declaration* is a type of statement, specifically it is a *declaration-statement*.  These include simple declarations like `int a=2`.